# how can I add a custom subject line below the \opening section of in scrlttr2 doc?

Tags: formatting, positioning, scrlttr2

I'm struggling with my first latex project and I need to add a subject line, and make it bold, below the opening salutation in letter.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 7):

`scrlttr2` supports an option that allows the placement of the subject after the opening/greeting:

```
\documentclass[subject=afteropening]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Mr. X}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Some Street 23 \\ Small Town}
\setkomavar{subject}{Very important stuff}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Mr. Y \\ Big Company \\ Capital City}
\opening{Dear Mr. Y,}

This is very important.

\closing{Best,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Other possible values (`centered, left, right, titled,...`) are explained in the very extensive manual ([scrguide.pdf](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguide.pdf) or [scrguien.pdf](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)).

Comment: That's great, thanks. I hadn't found that guide.

Comment: shame there's no subject=bold option though

Comment: @sophie you can change the font via the usual mechanism of KOMA-Script, like so `\setkomafont{subject}{\normalcolor\bfseries}` (note that boldface is already the default for the subject font).

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `\setkomavar{subject}{Subject goes here}` in the preamble.